# Oracle timestamp difference greater than X hours/days/months

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I am trying to write a query to run on Oracle database. The table ActionTable contains actionStartTime and actionEndTime columns. I need to find out which action took longer than 1 hour to complete.

actionStartTime and actionEndTime are of timestamp type

I have a query which gives me the time taken for each action:

```
select (actionEndTime - actionStartTime) actionDuration from ActionTable
```

What would be my `where` clause that would return only actions that took longer than 1 hour to finish?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Subtracting two timestamps returns an interval.  So you'd want something like

```
SELECT (actionEndTime - actionStartTime) actionDuration
  FROM ActionTable
 WHERE actionEndTime - actionStartTime > interval '1' hour
```

Comment: I missed the data type. I deleted my answer and upvoted yours.