# Oracle SQL Query Where Timestamp is in Last 1 hour Using Systimestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, intervals

Using oracle 11g

I read another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616207/oracle-timestamp-difference-greater-than-x-hours-days-months) where interval '1' hour should work the same way I expect it to, so I am wondering why I would get different results from these two queries and maybe help better understanding how the interval query works...

The intention of these two queries is to get all records where they have been on the table for less than 1 hour.

select err_ts from tbl where err_ts > systimestamp-(1/24) order by err_ts desc;

```
30-JAN-15 02.14.48.000000000 PM
30-JAN-15 02.08.58.000000000 PM
30-JAN-15 01.49.09.000000000 PM
```

select err_ts from tbl where (systimestamp - err_ts) < interval '1' hour order by err_ts desc;

```
30-JAN-15 02.14.48.000000000 PM
30-JAN-15 02.08.58.000000000 PM
30-JAN-15 01.49.09.000000000 PM
30-JAN-15 01.28.40.000000000 PM
30-JAN-15 01.21.12.000000000 PM
30-JAN-15 01.17.06.000000000 PM
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a time zone issue see, for example, https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2013/04/16/systimestamp/ .  You may want localtimestamp rather than systimestamp in the latter query (it may depend on exactly what sort of timestamp `err_ts` is).

Comment: Out of interest, what does the first query return if you use `- interval '1' hour` instead? You're implicitly converting to a date type to subtract `(1/24)`, which loses the time zone.

Comment: @JustinCave seems like that has produced the fix when I change to localtimestamp for the first query.  you should post as answer so I can accept.  I am curious though should I think change the second query to also use localtimestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using localtimestamp rather than systimestamp solved the issue as implicitly converting to a date type to subtract (1/24) loses the time zone.